# How to clone and selectively change fields on cloned object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have been searching for a solution for this problem the whole day and I am getting nowhere.

**Situation:**
I want to clone a custom object, update a few fields and insert the cloned object into the database. The object `request__c` is a child object.

**My Approach:**

1. Create custom button on Request__c to call a Visualforce Page
2. Create Visualforce Page (see below)
3. Create ExtensionCreatorController (see below)

**My Problem:**
I am stuck at getting the data from the Visualforce page to my cloned request. I am not sure which tags I have to use and how to then insert the new object. Help would be massively appreciated. Also just pointer to **relevant** links/documents would be helpful.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Request__c" extensions="ExtensionCreatorController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Request Input"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Input Section" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Request__c.name}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMovein" value="{!Request__c.Moveindate__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMoveout" value="{!Request__c.Moveoutdate__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>`
```

**ExtensionCreatorController:**

```
public class ExtensionCreatorController {

private final Request__c requ;

public ExtensionCreatorController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.requ = (Request__c)stdController.getRecord();
}

public InsertClone () {
    cloneRequest = requ.clone();
    cloneReqeust.name = 'EX-'+requ.name;
    cloneRequest.Moveindate__c = */here Date to be specified in Visualforce Page/*;
    cloneRequest.Moveoutdate__c = */here Date to be specified in Visualforce Page/*;
    Insert cloneRequest
}}
```

Comment: By the way, thank you for posting a complete, well-specified, and well-formatted question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you have to perform a "clone" at all. You've currently wired your input fields on the Visualforce page directly to the standard controller's object, which is also the same object as `requ` based on your assignment in the constructor. `requ` is private and hence invisible to Visualforce, but the object it refers to is already exposed through the standard controller.

When you are ready to perform the clone operation in `InsertClone`, you can actually just clear the `Id` field from `requ` (which will have the data from the Visualforce page's input fields, since it's the same object as the standard controller's) and then perform an insert to create a new record. You don't need to call `clone()` or create the `cloneRequest` variable.

You do not need to assign the `Moveindate__c` and `Moveoutdate__c` fields, because that data entry is already handled by your Visualforce page's bindings.

You can simply assign the `Name` field as desired, and set the `Id` field to `null` before doing `insert requ`.

Edit: You do need to make sure that the object used by the standard controller contains all of the fields that you would like to be copied to the new object, including particularly any required fields. The standard controller automatically queries fields that it knows are required (those that are used in the Visualforce page by explicitly referencing them). For situations like this, where you want to have fields available in the object that *aren't* shown in the page, you need to inform the controller that it should query them for you.

There's a couple of ways to do this:

1. You can include a reference to the field in the Visualforce page. (Probably not what you want to do here). This makes sure the standard controller populates the field without further intervention from you.
2. Call [`addFields`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) on the standard controller with a list of the API names of the fields you want to be populated. Basically, in your extension's constructor,  you would do something like

   `stdController.reset();`
    `stdController.addFields(new List<String>{ 'Opportunity__c', 'Landlord__c', ET_CETERA__C });`
    `this.requ = (Request__c)stdController.getRecord();`
3. Call `addFields`, but use the Describe API to obtain a list of all writeable fields rather than specifying them by hand.

Whether you choose (2) or (3) depends on exactly what you want to replicate from the original record and whether all of the fields are meaningful for the new object.

Comment: David, thank you very much for your well structured reply! I just have one question regarding the insert, how would I go about triggering the insert action from my visualforce Page?

Comment: Most likely, you'd want to use an `<apex:commandButton>` component, with its action method set to `{! CloneRequest }`. You can then have that method return a `PageReference` for the new object, to navigate the user there: `return ApexPages.StandardController(requ).view();`

Comment: David! Thank you very much. I implemented your suggestions and am getting a `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Opportunity, Landlord]: [Opportunity, Landlord]
Error is in expression '{!InsertClone}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page mynewpagename: Class.ExtensionCreatorController.InsertClone: line 12, column 1` which I find surprising as I would expect requ to use the same data as the original object.

Comment: David, thank you very much for the detailed and helpful explanation. Unfortunately I am not exactly sure how I would go about calling addFields on the standard Controller. I checked the documentation you attached but still don’t quite understand it. I would tremendously appreciate if you could elaborate on that a bit.

Comment: I tried to elaborate a little - I hope that's helpful!

Comment: David, again thank you for your patience. I tried implementing your suggestion, but am still getting the exact same error. I did validate that the components are deployed to the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: You are amazing! Things seem to be working now, just have to figure out the redirect, I get an "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" error ... weird

Comment: I missed the `new ` operator before `ApexPages.StandardController`.

Comment: That makes sense :) I implemented it and made some other changes. I posted this as a follow up question, because it has little to do with the original question in my oppinion: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212231/apex-class-extension-encounters-system-stringexception-invalid-id

Comment: David I have to call on you again. I've got my class working so far with minor hickups, like the redirect is not yet working. I am currently trying to set up unit tests, which gives me a horrendous nightmare. All the formula fields evaluate to null, are thus not really testable. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74883/discussion-between-david-reed-and-fabian-bosler).