# Redirecting to new Record after inserting does not work

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

this is a follow-up question to: [How to clone and selectively change fields on cloned object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212170/how-to-clone-and-selectively-change-fields-on-cloned-object)

**Situation:**
I want to clone a custom object, update a few fields and insert the cloned object into the database. The object `request__c` is a child object. I have since learned that I don't even need to clone the object, but can just use the standard controller, change the field I want to change, null the id of the initial object, and then insert into the DB (see Controller below).

**My Problem:**
I am trying to redirect to the inserted record after insertion. However, all I see after inserting is a blank page.

**ExtensionCreatorController:**

```
public class ExtensionCreatorController {

    private final Request__c requ;

    public ExtensionCreatorController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        stdController.addFields(new List<String>{ 'Opportunity__c', 'Landlord__c', 'Billing_Address__c'});
        this.requ = (Request__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public System.PageReference InsertClone() {
        requ.Extension_of__c = requ.name;           
        requ.id = null;
        requ.BookingID__c = requ.name;
        requ.name = 'EX-'+requ.name;
        requ.BookingDateBackEnd__c = Date.today();
        insert requ;
        return new ApexPages.StandardController(requ).view();
}}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Request__c" extensions="ExtensionCreatorController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Request Input"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Input Section" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Request__c.name}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMovein" value="{!Request__c.Moveindate__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMoveout" value="{!Request__c.Moveoutdate__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>`
```

Comment: Do you have any action overrides on `Request__c`?

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling an **InsertClone** method from commandLink/button or action function.

```
<apex:page standardController="Request__c" extensions="ExtensionCreatorController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Request Input"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Input Section" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Request__c.name}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMovein" value="{!Request__c.Moveindate__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMoveout" value="{!Request__c.Moveoutdate__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
           <apex:commandButton action="{!InsertClone}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

In your Apex controller, You are not clonning properly. I would advise using standard Sobject clone.

```
public System.PageReference InsertClone() {
        Request__c cloned=req.clone(); 
        cloned.Extension_of__c = requ.name;           
        cloned.id = null;
        cloned.BookingID__c = requ.name;
        cloned.name = 'EX-'+requ.name;
        cloned.BookingDateBackEnd__c = Date.today();
        insert cloned;
        return new ApexPages.StandardController(cloned).view();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, I had an older version of the code included. I am indeed calling the InsertClone(). Tried your update, but still only see a blank page :(

Comment: I tested this code in my org to confirm. So Am sure this works. Are you testing it on classic or lightning?

Comment: I am currently developing on a sandbox in classic mode.